# Why is my tag wiki excerpt edit rejected?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits, tag-wiki-excerpt

I suggested [this tag wiki edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3148625), but three people rejected it with the reason "This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post.". But I don't see anything wrong with my edit, because before my edit, the tag wiki excerpt looked like this (in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari and IE; I've not tested in other browsers):
[image: HTML5 tag wiki excerpt]
Look at the last sentence, "including semantic structural elements such as **and .**" I thought there would be summed up some of the structural elements, but I don't saw any. When I clicked on the "improve tag wiki" link, I saw this:[image]
Here, the elements `<nav>` and `<section>` were listed, but in the excerpt, they weren't listed, because the browser treats them as HTML5 tags, not as plain text, so I changed every `<` into `&lt;` and `>` into `&gt;`, to make sure the browser would treat them as text.

So why is this edit rejected?

Comment: Because in the markdown view presented to reviewers, it looks like a pointless edit.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sadly, it's due to an issue with how the suggested edit is rendered in the review queue.  The review queue doesn't render the same way the actual page is.  In that queue it *appears*, to the untrained eye, that it was working before, and that your edit double-encoded the values.  When looking at the tag wiki normally one can see that your edit is in fact correct.

A better edit summary would have helped here, but that's the only thing I can think of that you could have done differently.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to what Servy said, usually it would be preferable to put such tags in code markup (backticks). This doesn't work in tag wiki excerpts, but maybe not all reviewers are aware of this.

Comment: You're right. I'll do that in the future. Thanks!